# GPIB connection to external device using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, serial-port, gpib

Is there a way to establish a GPIB connection using MATLAB **without** the instrument control Tool box? (I don't have it). Also is there a way for MATLAB to know what the external device's RS232 parameter values are ( Baud rate, stop bit etc..). For the RS232 connection I have the following code:

```
% This function is meant to send commands to Potentiostat Model 263A.

% A run includes turning the cell on, reading current for time t1, turning

% the cell off, waiting for time t2.

% t1 is the duration [secs] for which the Potentiostat must run (cell is on)

% t2 is the duration [secs] to on after off

% n is the number of runs 

% port is the serial port name such as COM1

function [s] = Potentiostat_control(t1,t2,n)

port = input('type port name such as COM1', 's')

s = serial(port);

set(s,'BaudRate', 9600, 'DataBits', 8, 'Parity', 'even', 'StopBits', 2 ,'Terminator', 'CR/LF'); 

fopen(s)

%fprintf(s,'RS232?')

disp(['Total runs requested = ' num2str(n)]) 

disp('i denotes number of runs executed so far..');

for i=1:n

    i

    %data1 = query(s, '*IDN?')

    fprintf(s,'%s','CELL 1'); % sends the command 'CELL 1'

    %fprintf(s,'%s','READI');

    pause(t1);

    fprintf(s,'%s','CELL 0');

    %fprintf(s,'%s','CLEAR');

    pause(t2);

end

fclose(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your GPIB question, does the GPIB card come with a callable library (DLL if you're on Windows)?  Matlab has an interface for [calling external libraries](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f43202.html).  The basic procedure is to have Matlab parse the header file using `LOADLIBRARY`, then view the available functions using `LIBFUNCTIONS` and call functions using `CALLLIB`.

For your RS232 question, I don't think there's any way for the host side to know the device side's parameters without external documentation.

Comment: Thanks mtrw. I will look in to it

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [National Instruments VISA](https://www.ni.com/visa/) and [NI 488.2](https://www.google.ch/search?q=download%20ni%20488.2).

First make sure that you checked the `VisaNS.NET API` in the NI-VISA Setup, see the following figure:

[image]

I'm using the `NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSession` over the .NET interface from MATLAB.

I've written the following MATLAB class that wraps NI VISA to MATLAB:

```
classdef Visa
    properties
        vi
        SrqMask
        SrqTimeout
    end
    methods
        function obj = Visa(resourceName)
            NET.addAssembly('NationalInstruments.VisaNS');
            obj.vi = NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSession(resourceName);
            obj.SrqMask = '*CLS;*ESE 1;*SRE 32';
            obj.SrqTimeout = 10000;
        end
        function obj = delete(obj)
            obj.vi.Dispose();
        end
        function obj = Dispose(obj)
            obj.vi.Dispose();
        end
        function obj = Write(obj, data)
            obj.vi.Write(data);
        end
        function data = ReadString(obj)
            data = char(obj.vi.ReadString());
        end
        function data = ReadByteArray(obj)
            data = obj.vi.ReadByteArray();
        end
        function data2 = Query(obj, data)
            data2 = char(obj.vi.Query(data));
        end
        function obj = SrqBegin(obj)
            obj.vi.EnableEvent(NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSessionEventType.ServiceRequest, ...
                NationalInstruments.VisaNS.EventMechanism.Queue);
            obj.vi.DiscardEvent(NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSessionEventType.ServiceRequest);
            obj.Write(obj.SrqMask);
        end
        function status = SrqEnd(obj)
            evt = obj.vi.WaitOnEvent(NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSessionEventType.ServiceRequest, ...
                obj.SrqTimeout);
            evt.Dispose();
            status = obj.vi.ReadStatusByte();
            obj.vi.DisableEvent(NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSessionEventType.ServiceRequest, ...
                NationalInstruments.VisaNS.EventMechanism.Queue);           
        end
        function obj = SrqWrite(obj, data)
            obj.SrqBegin();
            obj.Write(data);
            obj.SrqEnd();
        end
        function data2 = SrqQuery(obj, data)
            obj.SrqBegin();
            obj.Write(data);
            obj.SrqEnd();
            data2 = obj.ReadString();
        end
    end
end
```

I've added as well some methods to handle the SRQ request.

With the following code you can control GPIB instrument for example:

```
resourceName = 'GPIB0::20::INSTR'; % GPIB adapter 0, Instrument address 20
vi = Visa(resourceName);
idn = vi.QueryString('*IDN?');
```

A `MessageBasedSession` can be used to communicate with your instrument over GPIB, Ethernet or USB.

See as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388678/7556646.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the RS232 parameters, but for an instrument with tcpip, you can send SCPI commands really easy.

Here is an example where I send a SCPI command to a Rohde&Schwarz instuments. No VISA or IVI needed. Use port 5025.

```
t = tcpip('147.214.90.136', 5025); 
fopen(t); 
fprintf(t, '*IDN?');
fprintf(1, DataReceived)
```

Then close the connection when you are done:

```
fclose(t); 
delete(t); 
clear t
```