# Sending SCPI/GPIB commands over USB from C#

Tags: c#, usb, visa, gpib

I'm trying to communicate with some test equipment from C# over SCPI. I managed to communicate with one device that is connected through TCP/IP by using [this code example](http://na.support.keysight.com/fieldfox/help/Programming/webhelp/Examples/CSharp_Example_Program.htm).

However, my other devices are connected through USB and I haven't find how to communicate with them over USB.

BTW, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232384/c-sharp-visual-studio-gpib-commands), and the link from the answer to the [IVI-COM programming examples in C#](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5991-0603EN.pdf) document, but I couldn't apply the code samples (e.g. in section 5.4) because all of the IVI and VISA COM libraries I found (e.g. VisaComLib 5.5) has only interfaces and enums in it, and no concrete class that I can use...

Answer (score 1):

If you install the visa driver from either NationalInstruments or Keysight, they do implement classes:

The one from NI:

1. FormattedIO488Class
2. ResourceManagerClass
3. VisaConflictTableManagerClass

To get a connection, you only need 1 and 2

As soon as you try to embed the interoptypes, you need to remove the 'Class' suffix, as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mshneer/2009/12/07/vs-2010-compiler-error-interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead/)

Here comes a sample snippet from Keysight (Application Note: 5989-6338EN)

```
Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager rm = new Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager();
Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488 ioobj = new Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488();

try
{

    object[] idnItems;

    ioobj.IO = (Ivi.Visa.Interop.IMessage)rm.Open("GPIB2::10::INSTR",
    Ivi.Visa.Interop.AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 0, "");

    ioobj.WriteString("*IDN ?", true);

    idnItems = (object[])ioobj.ReadList(Ivi.Visa.Interop.IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any, ",");

    foreach(object idnItem in idnItems)
    {
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine("IDN Item of type " + idnItem.GetType().ToString());
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine("\tValue of item is " + idnItem.ToString());
    }

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{

    try { ioobj.IO.Close(); }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ioobj);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rm);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [National Instruments VISA](https://www.ni.com/visa/).

Add a reference to `NationalInstruments.VisaNS` and `NationalInstruments.Common` to your project.

Create a `MessageBasedSession`, see the following code:

```
string resourceName = "USB0::0x0957::0x0118::US56070667::INSTR"; // See NI MAX for resource name
var visa = new NationalInstruments.VisaNS.MessageBasedSession(resourceName);
visa.Write("*IDN?"); // write to instrument
string res = visa.ReadString(); // read from instrument
```

See as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388678/7556646.